# Akka Http get query returning empty response

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm fumbling my way through `akka-http`; I've got a single route that compiles:

```
  val route = get {
    pathPrefix("compass") {
      path("route") {
        parameters(('srclat.as[Double], 'srclon.as[Double], 
          'destlat.as[Double], 'destlon.as[Double])) {
            (srclat, srclon, destlat, destlon) =>
              complete(getRoute((LatLong(srclat, srclon), 
                LatLong(destlat, destlon))))
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

And I've verified that the parameters are being extracted correctly.  When I call the method (with valid lat / longs), I'm expecting to receive an array of coordinates representing a (physical) route, but instead I receive a route object with an empty list of coordinates.  Here's the signature of the method being run by `complete`:

```
// the Route here is a domain object, not an akka-http Route   
def getRoute(coordinates: (LatLong, LatLong)): 
  Future[Option[Route]] = ???
```

And starting the server itself looks something like this:

```
val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(service.route, "0.0.0.0", 
  port)
```

I'm using `akka` and `akka-streams` 2.5.4 and `akka-http` 10.0.9, with Circe support from [hseeberger](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json) (version 1.18.0).  If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here, please let me know...any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> instead I receive a route object with an empty list of coordinates.

I think the problem is not in the code shown, but somewhere inside the `getRoute` function.

I have a hunch that you might be making changes to an immutable case class, and returning a previous copy, rather than the updated version?

e.g. code like the following would give the bug you describe:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

trait LatLong

case class Route(steps: List[String]) // for example

def getRoute(coordinates: (LatLong, LatLong)): Future[Option[Route]] = {
  val myRoute = new Route(Nil)

  val steps = List("one", "two", "three")

  myRoute.copy(steps = steps) // BUG HERE, new copy discarded

  Future(Some(myRoute))
}
```

If that doesn't explain things, please could you show more of the `getRoute` function?

A quick test to narrow things down might be to change `getRoute` temporarily to return a hardcoded non-empty Route, and check that it comes back OK over HTTP.

Comment: There's no mutation at all taking place (or copying of case classes)...The method looks like:  `def getDistance(coordinates: (LatLong, LatLong)): Future[Option[Distance]] =
    Future(distanceService.distance(coordinates._1, coordinates._2))`, where the distance service just looks the points up in an in-memory graph (created / populated before the service is called) and finds the shortest route between the points.  Right now everything compiles, but I'm just getting an empty Route object (which contains no data).  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I still think the same. The fact that you see an empty Route object in the HTTP client suggests to me that the Akka-HTTP part of your code is OK, but the bit which generates the Routes is broken. What happens if you replace "getRoute" with some temp code that returns a hardcoded non-empty Route?

Comment: It returns the correct response, but so does calling the `getRoute` method directly.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but so far I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

This was completely my fault; due to a cut-and-paste error, the source coordinates were being sent in as both source and destination, so the empty Route object was legitimate.  Thanks to those who took their time looking into my screw-up!

Comment: Thanks for updating. I thought it would be a problem in the code not shown. Maybe close the question, if you don't want to accept my answer?

Comment: Good call; Thanks for your help Rich!

Comment: I should note: Rich's suggestion is worth taking into account if you receive a similar error; although the cause of mine was different, this is still good information.